# Lexical Binding in Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

```
(let ((a 3))
  (let ((a 4)
        (b a))
    (+ a b)))
```

The above code evaluates to 7 the logic being that b takes the value of outer `a`. According to my understanding, in lexical binding each use of 'let' creates a fresh location. So why is the variable `b` in the statement `(b a)` not using the value of `a` from `(a 4)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because that's what `LET` is specified to do. Bindings are done in *parallel*.

```
CL-USER 60 > (let ((a 3))
               (let ((a 4)
                     (b a))
                 (+ a b)))
7
```

The version where bindings are done in a *sequential* fashion is called `LET*`.

```
CL-USER 61 > (let ((a 3))
               (let* ((a 4)
                      (b a))
                 (+ a b)))
8
```

See [Special Operator LET, LET*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm).

Comment: and what exactly do we mean by lexical environment of a name? does it refer to its scope?

Comment: @hubble Essentially, yes. The lexical environment is for all practical purposes the same as the lexical scope. The dynamic environment is dependent on exact call path at the time of execution.

Answer (score 1):

```
(let ((a 4)
      (b a))
  (+ a b)) ; ==> 7
```

Is equivalent to writing:

```
((lambda (a b)
   (+ a b))
 4
 a) ; ==> 7
```

Do you see from this version that it's logical that `a` and `b` are bound after the evaluation of `4` and `a`?

Now we have:

```
(let* ((a 4)
       (b a))
  (+ a b)) ; ==> 8
```

which is equivalent to:

```
(let ((a 4))
  (let ((b a))
    (+ a b))) ; ==> 8
```

Here the second `let` is in the body of the first. `a` is `4` when the expression for `b` is evaluated.